# Why do I have to delete _id field in Mongo before updating?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My update that find a document, changes some fields and updates:

```
newdocument = db.collection.findOne{"id_" : ObjectId("2bfc42346cb2f36c4f3fc6264c")}
newdocument.somefield = "New value" 
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("2bfc42346cb2f36c4f3fc6264c")}, newdocument)
```

does nothing unless, I remove the `_id` field from newdocument, i.e. `del newdocument["_id"]`. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: the _id is immutable it cannot be allowed to be updated, I think you are looking to use `save` instead

Comment: ... or skip the findOne and do the update atomically in place if your changes are fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is immutable but the structure you wrote also not needed to use. Simply:

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("2bfc42346cb2f36c4f3fc6264c")}, {$set:{"somefield":"New value"}})
```

will work